# Anime about a boy who defeated a creature that attacked his father's bakery, and then went on an adventure where he met some ladies in a forest

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd like to find an anime I watched on Netflix a few years ago. This is all I remember about it:

The protagonist was a young boy who lived with his father that was a baker. The bakery got invaded by some corrupted creature one day and the little boy defeated it and took whatever was inside it. I think it was like a sword with an eye.

The next thing I remember was he went on an adventure and found some friends in a forest (who were both ladies). I also remember there was an episode inside of a locked Rapunzel-style tower, where some monster girls were trying to get him to love them or whatever?

I honestly don't remember anything else, but it was a fantasy anime with magic and stuff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, what colour was the boy's hair?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw this comment. It was around 2016-2017 and I think the boy was a blonde? Either that or a ginger.

Comment: Is it Wakfu? Not really Japanese animation, but French.